# How to detect low performance mobile via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

While users open my website, I want to turn off some animation effects if the current performance of the user's device is low.

What's the best practise to ranking the device's performance? For example there are 10 ranks, for the devices below rank 5, I will use different way to show some effects.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around a device database with precompiled benchmark metrics for general mobile browser users. I am not aware of such a database, since most of them have capabilities and not performance in mind.

However, if you want to package it in a WebView container, you could probably run the benchmark yourself in a separate hidden WebView when the user isn't doing anything.